# Andengine - handler.postDelayed doesn't work

Tags: java, android, handler, andengine, postdelayed

I want to do a simple action in my game after one second. I have my GameScene class which extends Andengine's Scene.

```
public class GameScene extends Scene{
   //(...)
   Handler delayHandler;

   public GameScene(){
      Looper.prepare();
      delayHandler = new Handler();
   }
   //(...)

   public void sphereTouched(){
      //(...)
      delayHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         public void run(){
            Log.d("DEB","postDelayed test");
         }
      }, 1000); 
   }
}
```

When sphereTouched function is called operation from postDelayed doesn't run. Others operations from that function work properly. Have I missed something?

Comment: y dont u use Asynctask?

Comment: did you initialize delayHandler?

Comment: I don't know if this is related (perhaps you have two separate handlers and only initializing one?) or not (maybe just a mistake in the code posted here), but note that you're using `delayHandler` in `sphereTouched` but only initializing `handler` in the constructor.

Comment: anything in the log ?

Comment: @kabuko - sorry, i made a mistake when was writing a question. There's a delayHandler in constructor (I just corrected it).

Comment: @njzk2 - there's no messages related to handler in LogCat

Comment: is it possible that you are never releasing the thread you are working on (is sphereTouched method called from a loop in a run method, for example?)

Answer (score 0):

use this code for handler.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: how is it any different?

Comment: @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code
        }

Comment: Indeed, i missed @Override annotation, but nothing has changed when I added it.

Comment: check sphereTouched() method is invoked??

Comment: @surbiks - Yes, it is. There're also other operations in that method, which work fine.